# iOS/Swift how update Table View in Real Time

Tags: ios, swift, api, uitableview

I need to to fetch realtime news from API, and then show them in a `UITableView`, news must disappear 5 seconds after their arrival.

I am new in Swift, I know that UITableView has `reloadData()` that is meant to update the data in the table, I suppose I should use this method.

My idea is to call the Api every 5 seconds, but how it works update/animation for making disappearing the news and adding new ones in the table?

Comment: Rows can be animated with `insertRows(at:with:)` and `deleteRows(at:with:)` of `UITableView`, both operations can be performed simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the data from api, update your Data_Source(i.e. the list or array from which you are populating the `UITableView`) and after that call `reloadData()`. So `UITableView` will reload every time the data comes from api.

If you want to show only the new data then `assign` `=` the new data to your array, or want to add/append then `append` new data in old array.

Comment: Thank you. Any suggest about animation for making data disappearing?

Comment: try using `UIView.animate` method